# Group all identified overlapping dates in a dataset

Tags: .net, algorithm, date

Looking for an optimized way to find all overlaps in comparing two START_DATE/END_DATE fields and then grouping their respective ranges.

**Real World Problem Statement**:

A teacher may have multiple class assignments (driven by START/END dates, where end date may or may not be null. A business rule is needed to check all overlapping dates and group them, so we can check if in a certain overlapping period, a teacher does not exceed a total assignment load of x.

Lets assume x = 1, and the following sample dataset:

`ID    X      START_DATE       END_DATE
 1     1.0    "01-sep-2015"    "30-nov-2015" 
 2     0.5    "20-nov-2015"    "20-dec-2015" 
 3     0.5    "30-nov-2015"    "15-dec-2015" 
 4     0.5    "01-dec-2015"    NULL`

**Approach**

1. Using a nested loop, compare START/END dates of all the date ranges:
   1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4;
   2 -> 3, 3 -> 4;
   3 -> 4
   `overlap = a.start < b.end && b.start < a.end;`
2. Group all overlaps in a common set and determine if the sum of (X <= 1):

This is where I am having trouble. It's possible for X to be any decimal value below 1, so it may be possible to have 5 overlapping periods and still not equate to the desired rule. How can i best record all possible overlapping periods (unless i don't have to?) to determine if any OL period holds a sum of X greater than 1?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could build a graph `G = (V,E)` such that `V = {v_i | i = 1,2,3...} is the set of periods` and `E = {(vi,vj) | vi,vj in V AND vi overlaps vj}`. Also, the vertices in `V` is weighted by the weight of the task.

The graph encodes all possible overlapping periods. You could query all overlapping periods during period `p` by finding all neighbours of `p`. The weight of tasks in this period is found simply by adding the weight of neighbours of `p` AND the weight of `p` itself.

Building `G` costs `O(V^2)` (equivalent of your nested loop). But if you encode `G` as incident list (and not adjacency matrix), then you potentially finds ALL overlapping periods (and their associated weight) in `O(E)`- if your graph is sparse enough, it will be faster than `O(V^2)`.